# Switching from rx.Observable to rx.Single

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using rx.Observable all over my code and when I moved to a newer version of RxJava I have the need to switch to rx.Single.

Here is an example of how I use rx.Observable in my code:

```
obj.doSomething()
.filter(res -> {
  return res.getStatus() == 0 ? true : false;
})
.subscribe(res -> {
  handleResult(res);
});
```

With the new rxJava version, I had to change `doSomething()` to return rx.Single, so I can't use `.filter()` anymore making me handle its code in the `.subscribe()`.

I don't like it so much because it was nice having a special .filter block that used to handle the control and in case of `false` it would NOT reach the `.subscribe()`.

Any workaround or better design to avoid handling the boilerplate code in `.subscribe()`?

Comment: You do have [filter](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#filter(io.reactivex.functions.Predicate))  on `Single` in RxJava 2.

Comment: Don't you try doOnSuccess and throw exception in case of failed condition?

Comment: I'm still using RxJava v1.x

Comment: I don't throw exceptions in my code, but rather have enum with different status codes.

Comment: Try to change convert single to observable with toObservable().

Comment: Yeah - converting is kinda solution - but it's like cheating the API :-)

Comment: How do you guys handle such a case where you would like to check the return value of the rx.Single<Obj> and cut the chain if it's not what you expect?

Comment: I don't understand did you migrate to Rxjava2 or not. because I'm little confused.